# Setting new Date() by number and string gives different result

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript and I found weird(?) behavior of JavaScript.

I create date objects by

```
var stack = new Date(1404187200000) // 07-01-2014
var overflow = new Date('07-01-2014')
```

And when I compare those two date objects

```
stack == overflow // returns false
stack.getTime() == overflow.getTime() // returns true
```

And I believe it's because they are not the same object.  But I know that '==' is comparison of *equality* and '===' is comparison of *identity* - like this example:

```
var stack = 1;
var overflow = '1';
stack == overflow // returns true
stack === overflow // returns false
```

So, why does comparing **new Date([NUMBER])** and **new Date([STRING])** give a different result even though they are the same date?

Please enlighten me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the difference between `==` and `===`. It's not that one does equality checking and one does reference checking.

For `===`, the two operands have to have the same type. But for `==`, type coercion is allowed before checking for equality.

In your case, the two objects are of the same type, so there's no difference between `==` and `===`; but they are checking reference equality, not value. The right way to check for value equality with dates is as you're doing: check whether `stack.getTime() == overflow.getTime()`.

You can also do `+stack == +overflow`, which will cast them both first, and then you'll get a value equality test.

Comment: Why adding '+' sign will cast it first?

Comment: @KimchiMan a date can't be positive or negative. A `+` will force it to become something that can take a sign (or can be added to zero).

Answer (score 1):

`new Date` returns an object.  Each time you create it it will create a different object, so they're not equal.  `getTime` returns a value (property) from the object-- this will be the same for both objects.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little bit more complicated. `===` checks the type while `==` tries to convert to a common type. That's why `1 == '1'` is true but `1 === '1'` is false, because in the first case '1' gets transformed to a number (AFAIR).

you can see the exact specification how that is handled here: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3 - the interesting part for you in this case is 1. f.

> Return true if x and y refer to the same object. Otherwise, return false.